# Count of different word styles as csv file

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need count of different word styles in the word document as a CSV file with column headers Style name and Styles Count.

My VB code for output as a popup for particular style in the word document.

```
Sub Count()
Dim l As Long
ResetSearch
With ActiveDocument.Range.Find
   .Style = "Strong" 'Replace with the name of the style you are counting
   While .Execute
      l = l + 1
      If l > ActiveDocument.Range.Paragraphs.Count Then
         Stop
      End If
   Wend
End With
MsgBox l
ResetSearch
End Sub

Public Sub ResetSearch()
With Selection.Find
   .ClearFormatting
   .Replacement.ClearFormatting
   .Text = ""
   .Replacement.Text = ""
   .Forward = True
   .Wrap = wdFindContinue
   .Format = False
   .MatchCase = False
   .MatchWholeWord = False
   .MatchWildcards = False
   .MatchSoundsLike = False
   .MatchAllWordForms = False
   ' plus some more if needed
   .Execute
End With
End Sub
```

Output I am getting count of styles as a popup message box.

Please suggest that different styles in word not only strong any type of style count in csv format column headers are Style name and Styles Count

Answer (score 0):

Try something based on the following. It's not clear, though, what you mean about an output in CSV format.

```
Sub GetDocStyles()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim StrStl As String, StrStls As String, j As Long
StrStls = "Style" & vbTab & "Count"
With ActiveDocument.Range
  .Font.Hidden = True
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Format = True
    .Font.Hidden = True
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Text = "?"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Execute
  End With
  Do While .Find.Found = True
    StrStl = .Paragraphs.First.Style
    StrStls = StrStls & Chr(11) & StrStl
    j = 0
    With .Duplicate
      With .Find
        .Style = StrStl
        .Text = ""
        .Execute
      End With
      Do While .Find.Found = True
        j = j + 1
        .Font.Hidden = False
        .Find.Execute
      Loop
    End With
    StrStls = StrStls & vbTab & j
    .Find.Execute
    DoEvents
  Loop
End With
With ActiveDocument.Range
  .InsertAfter vbCr & "The following paragraph Styles were found in the document:" & Chr(11) & StrStls
  .Paragraphs.Last.TabStops.Add Position:=InchesToPoints(1.5), Alignment:=wdAlignTabRight
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: its deleting the content in the word doc